# Story about a mixed race user who learns to use magic

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm trying to find the name of a (YA?) story / series that I read 15 - 20 years ago. Here's what I remember :

- There were 3 races in the story. I think one race had pink skin.
- The protagonist was mixed from the different races.
- There was magic, but the protagonist wasn't magical (at least not at first).
- Something about iron structures in a city.
- There was a tower (perhaps in a second book?) with lapis lazuli.
- There was a scene where characters made homemade "wine" (something to do with the tower).

I wish I could remember more about the plot of the book / series, which is kind of why I want to find it again. I never finished the whole thing.

Comment: As in bright pink skin? Or just, like, caucasian human pink skin?

Comment: A mixed race *what*? What is a "user"? Was a word left out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this may be Ian Irvine's **View From the Mirror** quartet. See if [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_View_from_the_Mirror) triggers any memories. Published between 1998 and 2001, so fits with your timeframe.

Three races: check. There are actually four, but that doesn't emerge until later.

Pink skin. Half a check. The races were differently coloured with the Faellem having transluscent skin.

The protagonist was mixed race. Check. In fact, that's a fundamental plot point.

The protagonist wasn't magical at first. Check. Again, a fundamental plot point.

Tower in the second book. Check. The second book was called The Tower on the Rift.

Lapis lazuli.  Check. A quote describing the tower from the second book:

> Halfway up, at least eighty spans, was a vertical band of polished lapis lazuli, brilliantly blue in the golden afternoon light, with narrow gold bands at bottom and top.

Wine? Maybe. Can't remember.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!